# Long equation labelled by a symbol

Tags: equations, labels

To label a single symbol to long equation, we use \begin{split}...\end{split}:

```
   \begin{align}\label{eq1}
   \begin{split}
   H=\langle x_1,x_2,\cdots, x_n \colon & [x_i,x_j,x_k]=1,\\
                                              & [x_i,x_j]^p=1 \rangle.
   \end{split}
   \end{align}
```

To label an equation by a symbol say (*), we use \tag{ } inside \begin{equation}.

```
\begin{equation}
E=mc^2\tag{*}
\end{equation}
```

**Question:** If I want to label a long equation by a single symbol, how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have very nearly answered your own question.

`\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}` should be used for display math that
consists of a single formula, i.e., has only one equation "number".
`split` can be used within `equation`, and is recommended (read the
documentation, please).  so

```
\begin{equation}\label{eq1}
\begin{split}
H=\langle x_1,x_2,\cdots, x_n \colon & [x_i,x_j,x_k]=1,\\
                                          & [x_i,x_j]^p=1 \rangle.
\end{split}
\tag{*}
\end{equation}
```

will do exactly what you want.

Comment: Or `aligned`. But the main request is to also use something like `\tag{<symbol>}`.

Comment: sorry, I didn't get your your answer. where we use \tag here?

Comment: @pGroups -- sorry, not paying proper attention.  fixed now.

Comment: @barbara: Thanks. (Actually, I was checking this by adding \tag{ } at different places inside \begin{equation...\end{equation}, but it was giving errors. Then I thought that there may be some different way for it, hence posted the question above.)